# Handle Angular Proxy 404 [intended] error

Tags: json, angular, proxy

I have a simple proxy configuration as follows:

```json
{
  "/preview": {
    "target": "https://localhost:44323",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/preview": ""
    },
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

But the following URI cannot be reached (this is intended). I want to implement some specific behaviour on this. But I can't catch it with error interceptor & didn't find any examples on the internet.

I want to insert some site (that can be offline) as an iFrame in site. If site is offline want to display some custom page.

What I get instead of content:

```
Error occured while trying to proxy to: localhost:44323/?eventId=e4813a1c-918f-4e74-b525-7d5817256ac1
```

P.S. Potential use of this is much broader, than is provided.

Comment: Could you give some context: what URI can't be reached, what currently happens and what do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thanks, updated the question.

Comment: This seems like _actual functionality_, not something you should be doing with the dev server's proxy.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, ok, another example, i wanna connect to another server if first is offline, but if error occured, front end will use localhost:4200 (app url)[and no error]. I want to change behaviour to the following:at list throw error if server can not be reached(proxied).

Comment: I want to get and handle such error if proxy connection fails.

Comment: Again, bear in mind this is the dev server. It's just for local development, to simplify config while you work on the app (see e.g. this setup I put together: https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/wiki/Architecture). What you're describing is much more complex than that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, this is so weird that if endpoint can not be reached app simply use ...:4200(app base url) to send request(app sends request to itself) but there is no error is throwing to inform and allow to handle.

Comment: But if I do not use proxy(simple direct request with url provided), then error will be thrown  as  it `should be` with normal error message, that endpoint can not be reached. I always believed, that proxy is intended to be 'kind of invisible' for app and should not change its behaviour.